# Generic term for songs, movies, TV episodes, etc

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, hypernyms

For the model of a software project, I need a generic term that is abstract enough to encompass a single song, TV episode, movie, audiobook, etc.

The word *content* comes to mind, but it is plural. The words *entity* and *item are* much too ambiguous.

Any ideas?

Comment: Content is not necessarily plural - it can be a mass/uncountable noun.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about *composition*?

The *Associated Press Stylebook*'s section on *composition* titles includes instructions on how to handle titles of:

> books, computer and video games, movies, operas, plays, poems, albums, songs and radio and TV shows, as well as the titles of lectures, speeches and works of art.

Comment: Composition seems like it would work great. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

How about "media item"? That's what I've seen similar software use.

Comment: I use "media clip" for playable content. While "clip" has connotations of brevity, it's merely short for "clipping," and relative: what's a feature film but a two-hour clip made from two hundred hours of footage.

Comment: I seem to recall the phrase "1000 media items in your library" used in some software; don't remember which one it was though.

Comment: Media without item would seem to be sufficient.

Comment: No, media is plural. Think what the user is doing with the software - "I would like to play a media" versus "I would like to play a media item".

Answer (score 2):

Use the word "Entertainment"....

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps terms like these:

media asset, media file, media clip.

Answer (score 0):

The most generic word creative people use is *piece*. You might consider *number*.

> *[Oxford Advanced Learner's Ditionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/piece_1?q=piece)* **piece** > [countable] a single item of writing, art, music, etc. that somebody has produced or created; a short item of writing from a longer work
>
> piece of something a piece of music/art
> a fine piece of writing
> They performed pieces by Bach and Handel.

> [Merriam-Webster Dictioanry](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/piece) **piece** 5
> : a literary, journalistic, artistic, dramatic, or musical composition

Answer (score -3):

How about: "PLAY" ?

This encompasses all of the sections that you require.

Comment: -1 "Play" is what you do to/with them - not what they ***are***.

Comment: Only in a theatrical sense.