# Word that covers Games, TV, Movies and Music

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Is there a word that covers Games, TV, Movies and Music?

Entertainment seems to be fitting but it's a bit too long for my needs and I'm looking for alternatives.

I searched and found 'Media' and 'Fiction' but I'm unsure if these two terms covers it too.

Comment: Related: [Hypernym for image, video, and audio](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91845/), [Hypernym for “movie” and “TV series”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/127196/), [Generic term for songs, movies, TV episodes, etc.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64070/), and more questions linked from these.

Comment: More to the point, how do you mean that you reject a word because it is a mere 13 letters long? You have some *very* specific requirements there, and the language simply was not designed with your website menu in mind (or whatever menu it is you are labelling). Your application should follow the language, not the other way round.

Comment: There's always "ent" (abbreviation for "entertainment")

Comment: I was simply asking if 'media' and 'fiction' work as alternatives.

Comment: Maybe *leisure.*

Comment: "Fiction" does not work at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nevertheless, [entertainment](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/entertainment) seems to be your word.

There are amusements, diversions, relaxation, escape, [etc.](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/entertainment?show=0&t=1387297966), but entertainment seems tailor made to your specifications.

Perhaps you are looking for something less formal as a question (*What do you do to* ***relax***?) Then you must tell us why entertainment does not fill your needs.

Comment: I guess I should have been more specific. I need it for a domain name, so I was looking for a short word.

Comment: Top level domain? Just use an abbreviation like .ent. The most famous one is not .commercial, nor do we have .government, .education, .organization, or .military. Left as a comment and not an answer because it was not the OP question and if it were it would be an IT or business question, nog an ELU.