# What is the common name/word for movies, games, songs, books etc?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, hypernyms

English is not my main language. I am trying to find a word or a phrase (2 or 3(!) words maximum) to make a reference to these actions for an article.

What is the common name for these kind of actions:

- playing video games
- watching movies/series
- reading books
- listening songs
  etc..

I came up with "having fun" but this seems too generic and the purpose of most of these actions are not just to have fun. I am looking at "hobby" but not all hobbies are bound to a product of some company/artist like movies/songs/games/books do.

Comment: Leisure activities. Pastimes.

Comment: "Playing games" includes physical games, like football and tennis?  Or only games you play sitting down with a computer screen?  If the latter, call all these "couch potato activities".

Comment: "Recreation" or "recreational activities" would be my choice.

Comment: Watching movies, reading books, and listening to music are examples of ***passive** entertainment*. Playing games (physical, such as football, or mental, such as chess) is a ***participatory** activity*. Any of these "pastimes" may involve "products" or other things you need to purchase, but that's not really central to the concepts.

Comment: Consuming media covers all but the games.

Comment: @GEdgar , "playing games" = "playing video games".

Comment: Another possibility would be ***"avocations"***. Normally I would say all of the activities given by you fit the terms Edwin suggested. Nevertheless I can see that some of the activities may be too draining to be described by leisure. In that case, I would go with avocations

Comment: possible duplicate of [Word that covers Games, TV, Movies and Music](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/142178/word-that-covers-games-tv-movies-and-music)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **consuming entertainment.**

**Consuming media** would also work for all the types of entertainment you listed except for playing video games — the reason being that that particular pastime involves considerably more (inter)activity than the others, which are all relatively passive forms of entertainment.