# I need a word that is used for literature, movies, and books

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a word that you would use that encompasses all tree of literature, movies, and books. I'm doing an art project and the theme is “words I like”, and I want a word that you can say and it includes all three. I've already thought of *Fine Arts* or *the Arts*, but I don't think that works.

Comment: Fiction:  The category of literature, drama, film, or other creative work whose content is imagined and is not necessarily based on  fact.

Comment: Similar: *[Word that covers Games, TV, Movies and Music](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/142178)*, *[A generic term for both books and movies?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/235654)*, *[What is the common name/word for movies,games,songs,books etc?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/223486)*, *[Generic term for songs, movies, TV episodes, etc](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/64070)*, *[Hypernym for “movie” and “TV series”](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/127196)*, *[Word or words to encompass TV and Books](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/259195)*, and so on.

Comment: You haven't explained how you'll use it: are you after a noun? An adjective? Give us an example sentence with X marking the place of the word you want.

Comment: Literature, in print and film.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a comment, **"fiction"** can fit but it doesn't include documentaries, technical books, biographies, etc.

I suggest **"fictional arts"** (movies, theater, literature)

Answer (score 0):

"Literature, movies and books" tell stories. I think that's the main commonality. *Narrative* and *storytelling* speak directly to that concept.