# Word or words to encompass TV and Books

Tags: phrase-requests

I would like to create a tag on my blog for when I post about TV shows and books. Word+Film comes to mind, but I would prefer to make it more about TV shows rather than film. Or TV in general. Thanks for the help!

Comment: "Media" (technically a plural word) is the term that encompasses everything -- books, newspapers, films, TV, radio, internet news, etc.

Comment: What kind of content will be on the blog? Reviews of TV/Books? Suggestions for new shows or stories? Unless you intend to have different tags for posts about music, video games, movies, newspapers etc., I would agree with the suggestion of "media" if you wanted a separate word for it. Though personally I would tag such posts as "TV/Books", or probably just separate them totally into different tags.

Comment: Similar: *[Generic term for songs, movies, TV episodes, etc](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64070)*; *[Hypernym for “movie” and “TV series”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/127196)*; *[Word that covers Games, TV, Movies and Music](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/142178)*; *[Hypernym for image, video, and audio](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91845)*.

Answer (score 1):

From the OED:

> [media](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/115635) (plural of medium), n.
>
> The main means of mass communication, esp. newspapers, radio, and television, regarded collectively; the reporters, journalists, etc., working for organizations engaged in such communication. Also, as a count noun: a particular means of mass communication.

---

> [medium](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/115772#eid37559483), n.
>
> A channel of mass communication, as newspapers, radio, television, etc.; the reporters, journalists, etc., working for organizations engaged in such communication.